# Truncate/Trim the Date & Time form each line of a list

Tags: python, regex, trim, truncate

I have a list which is an email body and each line has a date & time stamp at the end. The format of the stamp is consistent so the expression can be calculated from the right. Below is sample data:

```
Dear Volunteer2018-05-21 19:59:15
Your booking has been updated at metrowitnessing.com .2018-05-21 19:59:15
Crown Street - June 15th, 10:00am2018-05-21 19:59:15
Anthony James (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Monica Brown (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Bob Smith (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Status: Confirmed2018-05-21 19:59:15
```

Have tried the following expression with no result, which 'body' is the sample data listed above.

```
import re
SourceList = input_data['body']
OutputList = filter(
lambda ThisWord: not re.match('^(?:(?:[0-9]{4}[:\/,]){2}[0-9]{2}|am|pm)$', ThisWord),
SourceList)
```

for ThisValue in OutputList:
  print ThisValue

What expression can I use to remove the date & time stamp that is attached to the end of each line?

Comment: please show what you have attempted so far..

Comment: please edit the post to include what you have added in the comment..

Answer (score 1):

Use `readlines` to load file to list and then you can iterate over it truncating last 19 characters (`[:-19]`). This is hardcoded and ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Split by lines :

```
lines = body.splitlines()
```

For each line in lines :

```
n = 19 #number of characters to trim
line = line[:-n]
```

Code :

```
lines = body.splitlines()
output = ""
for line in lines:
   output += line[:-19] + "\n"
#output now contains the trimmed body 
print(output)
```

Comment: Sorry @vbuzze, I tried your method but it didn't seem to work. Is the expression composed of 2 lines?

Comment: You first gotta split your body into lines, it gives you an array of lines (*string*). Then for each of these lines do ```line = line[:-19]``` assuming your current line is stored into the variable ```line```. You now have a array of trimmed lines. You can join them back into a single string if necessary.

Comment: Please up and mark as answer if this issue is closed

Comment: I am using Zapier and when I ran the Python code, the following error resulted:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpMyzEIB/usercode.py", line 10, in the_function
    output += line[:-19] + "\n"
NameError: global name 'line' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what format your data was in to start with.

If it's stored like this

```
text = 'Dear Volunteer2018-05-21 19:59:15 Your booking has been updated at metrowitnessing.com .2018-05-21 19:59:15 Crown Street - June 15th, 10:00am2018-05-21 19:59:15 Anthony James (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15 Monica Brown (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15 Bob Smith (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15 Status: Confirmed2018-05-21 19:59:15'
```

then you could do

```
import re
re.sub(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', '', text)
```

Comment: The data is HTML email body but when the HTML tags are removed you are left with the sample data. Not a comma separated list but email text over 6 or 7 lines

Comment: Ok, so in Python you've got something like this? `text = 'Dear Volunteer2018-05-21 19:59:15
Your booking has been updated at metrowitnessing.com .2018-05-21 19:59:15
Crown Street - June 15th, 10:00am2018-05-21 19:59:15
Anthony James (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Monica Brown (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Bob Smith (m: 04xxxxxxxx)2018-05-21 19:59:15
Status: Confirmed2018-05-21 19:59:15'`

Comment: Ok. Then what I've written returns the dates (and times) as a list - is this what you're after?

Comment: I wanted to remove the dates and times, retaining only the other data in each line

Answer (score 0):

Removing characters does not account for entries that do not have dates, therefore it's HIGHLY not recommended to use solutions that truncate lines without RegEx discrimination. You need an expression that searches for dates.

Try this expression:

This will match the beginning of the date and include the rest of the line.

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*
```

Comment: Thanks @4ur0r4 for your tip. How would I incorporate this expression into an expression that removes the dates have been discovered?

Comment: Create a function that finds the index within each line where the regular expression finds a match, and then you would remove all characters from there until the end of the line. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks @4ur0r4 for the tip. I am a complete newbie to Python. Is there any chance that you could formulate an expression based on your suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

For removing the data and timestamp use this reqex here:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

You can easily test on your sample data with any regex tester like https://regexr.com/.